# Why thread enters WaitSleepJoin state?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm coding singleton class that runs a background thread. Here is how it started and maintained:

```
 private void EnsureBackgroundThread()
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.RunnerThread == null)
                    this.RunnerThread = new Thread(this.BackgroundRunner) { IsBackground = true };

                if (this.RunnerThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("----ApplePushNotificatorService.EnsureBackgroundThread ThreadState: " + this.RunnerThread.ThreadState);
                    this.RunnerThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.LoggerService.Log(null, ex);
            }
        }
```

I call my method in this class from `TestClass` like so:

```
apns.Send("dev", devices, "Testing...", out badIds);

            // Wait 5 seconds to let it send stuff through.
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            devices.Clear();
            devices.Add("some bad id");

            // Now let's call this again, but this time we should get back some bad Ids
            apns.Send("dev", devices, "Testing...", out badIds);

            // Wait 5 seconds to let it send stuff through.
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            devices.Clear();
            devices.Add("9edc21d0d4e369f50040c5d2c94f2ea29c7d596090e4ddae253712cd406391df");
            apns.Send("dev", devices, "Test message for Andrew's phone", out badIds);

            // Wait 5 seconds to let it send stuff through.
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

I checked error logs and I see exceptions:

> Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart.

In debug it says:

> ----ApplePushNotificatorService.EnsureBackgroundThread ThreadState: Background, WaitSleepJoin

Why does it enter "WaitSleepJoin" state? Is it because I do "Thread.Sleep" in my test?

Does my code to keep thread alive look correct? How do I work around this? The idea is when "Send" method called on singleton - we need to make sure background thread is running.

EDIT:

This is re-worked code that is working properly

```
private void EnsureBackgroundThread()
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.RunnerThread != null && this.RunnerThread.IsAlive) return;
                this.RunnerThread = new Thread(this.BackgroundRunner) { IsBackground = true };
                this.RunnerThread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.LoggerService.Log(null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `IsAlive` instead of comparing `ThreadState`. There's a lot of reasons why a thread might not be `Running`, even though it didn't finish its work yet (including your `Thread.Sleep` call, but also when doing a `lock`, or when calling synchronous I/O). Also, multithreading shouldn't be done on a try-and-see basis. You should understand what's happening, otherwise you're pretty much guaranteed to get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Luaan Doing that you'd still end up trying to start the thread after it has terminated, which is also an error.

Comment: @Servy Yes, you're right. The underlying issue is, however, that the OP has no idea how to properly work with asynchronous (or parallel) operations.

Comment: We all learn, right? I do have ideas on how it works but doing it first time after studying is still not 100% hence a question to make sure.

Comment: @katit No harm done. The usual way to keep a thread alive is to have an infinite loop inside (with optional waits, depending on your use case). However, in your case, I wonder if you really need a background task at all. Is there a reason why you can't use `await` / `async` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately no, async/await won't work. And yes, I do infinite loop with Sleep(100). Apple dictates that connection to their push server should be kept open. So, I have to keep it spinning on background and constantly checking if there new data available to send.. Using locks around those exposed properties..

Comment: @Luaan thumbs up for the IsAlive vs ThreadState info, even though this wasn't related to the actual problem. It helped me in my own specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, as the error states: your thread has been created and is running or terminated - and then you try to start it again.

Presumably in your `TestClass` you have multiple calls to your singleton class (I'm guessing this may be somewhere under the `apns.Send` call). The first time you call `EnsureBackgroundThread`, a single thread will be created and started. The next time you call `EnsureBackgroundThread` will call `Thread.Start` *on the same thread*, thus causing the same error.

It's perhaps important to note here that, when a thread completes, the variable referencing it isn't set to `null` - but more likely you're just calling the `EnsureBackgroundThread` method more than once and the code you've written doesn't support that.

Answer (score 5):

The state tells us that the thread is currently sleeping, likely in one of your calls to `Sleep`.  This means it's still running.  Because it's still running, you cannot start it.  You're trying to start the same thread multiple times.  You can't do that.  You start it once, then it's started, and that's that.  Trying to start it a second time, either while it's running, or after it is done, is not possible.